# Remove random items from `Get-ChildItem` output

Tags: string, powershell

I'd like to ask a question about removing lines from a variable that has strings obtained from get-childitem.
Right now, I'm extracing lines indicating files with this :

`$FolderToOpen= Get-ChildItem -Path $SrcDir -Filter *.$ExtLst`

That gets the files from a specified folder and specified extensions
Then, I get 4 random lines from that variable

`$FourFiles = $FolderToOpen | Get-Random -Count 4`

But then, here's my problem, I'd like to delete those 4 lines from the first variable. However I can't get to do that,  doing

`$FolderToOpen -replace "$FourFiles",""`

for exemple doesn't do anything.
Could someone help me please?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of doing that is to take advantage of `Compare-Object` which compares arrays element-wise:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FolderToOpen -DifferenceObject $FourFiles -PassThru
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that **PowerShell prefers operating on objects instead of strings**. The output of `Get-ChildItem` is a stream of objects, what can be proven by piping it to `Get-Member`:

```
PS> dir | Get-Member 
TypeName: System.IO.DirectoryInfo
...
TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo
...
```

Since you are interested in particularly filtering strings, you can cast all the objects to strings beforehand and then perform filtering:

```
$FourFiles = $FolderToOpen | Get-Random -Count 4 | % {$_.ToString()}
$FolderToOpen | Where {$_.ToString() -inotin $FourFiles}
```

Note that `$FolderToOpen` is a stream of strings, instead of one big string like you would have in Bash. Therefore I used `Where` to filter the entries.

Comment: Thank you, I had found some woraround by doing some collections.queue as I could see about arrays and strings, but your answer helped me understand some things :D

Answer (score 0):

The `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet returns an array of objects by default and as such is of a fixed size (see [Everything you wanted to know about arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays?view=powershell-7.2#adding-to-arrays) for further information on this)

If we cast the results of the `Get-ChildItem` call to a list first, we'll then be able to add and remove items (without the need to create new arrays to hold the updated data)

Updated code below should give you what you're looking for:

```
# Call Get-ChildItem but store the results as a list of objects
# rather than a standard array of objects
[Collections.Generic.List[Object]]$FolderToOpen= Get-ChildItem -Path $SrcDir -Filter *.$ExtLst

# Get your random selection of 4 files
$FourFiles = $FolderToOpen | Get-Random -Count 4

# Remove them from the list 
$FolderToOpen.RemoveAll({ param($folder) $folder -in $FourFiles })
```

The `RemoveAll` function above will return the total number of entries removed from the list (in this example, 4).

Comment: Thank you, I had found some workaround by doing some collections.queue and dequeue, but I'd rather use your solution, I find it more clean :D

Answer (score 0):

A solution that uses only `Get-Random`. Basically use `Get-Random` to select the files to **include**, instead of exclude. Then you don't need to remove anything. The output of `Get-Random` is already what you want.

```sh
$FolderToOpen = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $SrcDir -Filter *.$ExtLst)

$includeCount = $FolderToOpen.Count - 4
$FolderToOpen = if( $includeCount -gt 0 ) { 
    $FolderToOpen | Get-Random -Count $includeCount 
}
```

- To make sure we always get an array out of `Get-ChildItem`, use the array sub-expression operator `@()`. Otherwise you'd get a single object, if `Get-ChildItem` outputs only a single file.
- The `if` statement is required to make sure we don't pass an invalid `-Count` argument to `Get-Random`, when `Get-ChildItems` returns four or less files.
- Note that this outputs the files in **random order**, but you could easily sort them by path again:

  ```sh
  $FolderToOpen | Get-Random -Count $includeCount | Sort-Object FullName
  ```